# Can i use google cloud as a hosting platform for my web and webmail

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-hosting, web

I am looking for a hosting service for my business webpage and webmail, i have been reading that google´s service is a good choose but i can not found so many information, can anyone help me please? Thank you for answering. Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have look at the documentation [Google Cloud web hosting](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-hosting) - you can choose from lots of ways to run your website. Also, you can easily configure mail service for you business using [Google Workspace](https://workspace.google.com).

---

Keep in mind, if you decide to use [GCE VM instance with LAMP](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp) for your business webpage you won't be able to send email directly from your VM. Accordingly to the documentation [Always blocked traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic) port 25 (which is used by [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)) is blocked.

In this case, to send emails you should follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#choosing_an_email_service_to_use) and use Google Workspace as a mail relay. Alternatively, you can use [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid), [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun) or [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet).